# How to install datawrapper locally?

Tags: ubuntu, d3.js, data-visualization

I would like to test Datawrapper locally. This is a web application which is a kind of  graphical user interface for D3js, a javascript library for data visualization.

I use Ubuntu 12.10 and I've already installed LAMP.

https://github.com/datawrapper/datawrapper

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the general installation notes of Datawrapper, which you can find here: http://docs.datawrapper.de/en/install/